# <OrgLocationsImport> fails with "A location/job with the name and path already exists"

Tags: xml, kronos-workforce-central

I want to update a job on an organizational map with the Kronos Workforce Central v8.1 XML API.

According to the [*Workforce Timekeeping v8.1 Developer's Toolkit Guide*](https://community.kronos.com/s/article/Workforce-Timekeeper-v8-1-Developer-s-Toolkit-Reference-Guide), sending a request with `<OrgLocationsImport>` and `Action="Update"` should update a job if it already exists. However, while I can import new jobs without issue, the request will fail if I try to update an existing job.

Error Message:

> WFP-00335 A location/job with the name TEST and path "ROOT/BU/DIV/SL/DEPT/TEST" already exists from 6/02/2010 to 12/31/2999.

XML Request:

```
<Kronos_WFC version="1.0">
    <Request Action="Update">
        <OrgLocationsImport ChangeDate="05/30/2018">
            <OrgLocations>
                <OrgLocation
                  ParentLocationPathName="ROOT/BU/DIV/SL/DEPT"
                  LocationName="TEST"
                  LocationType="Job"
                  Description="Test Job">
                </OrgLocation>
            </OrgLocations>
        </OrgLocationsImport>
    </Request>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

XML Response:

```
<Kronos_WFC TimeStamp="5/30/2018 10:18AM GMT-04:00" version="1.0" WFCVersion="8.1.1.569">
    <Response Status="Failure" Action="Update">
        <Error Message="WFP-00335 A location/job with the name TEST and path
            &quot;ROOT/BU/DIV/SL/DEPT/TEST&quot; already exists from 6/02/2010
            to 12/31/2999." ErrorCode="106" AtIndex="0">
            <ErrorData>"PATH=ROOT/BU/DIV/SL/DEPT/TEST""EFFECTIVE_DATE=6/02/2010"
                "EXPIRATION_DATE=12/31/2999""NAME=TEST"
            </ErrorData>
        </Error>
    </Response>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

**Why does my `<OrgLocationsImport>` update request fail if the location already exists?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `LocationPathName` when updating an `<OrgLocation>`.

```
<Kronos_WFC version="1.0">
    <Request Action="Update">
        <OrgLocationsImport ChangeDate="05/30/2018">
            <OrgLocations>
                <OrgLocation
                  ParentLocationPathName="ROOT/BU/DIV/SL/DEPT"
                  LocationPathName="ROOT/BU/DIV/SL/DEPT/TEST"
                  LocationName="TEST"
                  LocationType="Job"
                  Description="Test Job">
                </OrgLocation>
            </OrgLocations>
        </OrgLocationsImport>
    </Request>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

According to the WFC documentation, an `<OrgLocation>` should always include either a `LocationPathName` or a `LocationNum`. Excluding them should be considered undefined behavior.

Interestingly, when these attributes are excluded from an `<OrgLocationsImport>` request in WFC v6.3 and v8.1, the request seems to act as a makeshift `AddOnly` action. However, this behavior may change in future versions of Workforce Central.